# How do i loop this array?

Tags: php

```
    $datadiri = array(
        "Bimo Nasuti" => array (
            "mob" => "6545444455",
            "email" => "bimonasuti@gmail.com",
            "hp" => "08123456787",

        ),
        "Bimo Nasuti" => array (
            "mob" => "6545444455",
            "email" => "bimonasuti@gmail.com",
            
        ),
        "Yuni Salam" => array (
            "mob" => "512512662",
            "email" => "yunisalam@gmail.com",
            "hp" => "08123456787",

        )
    );
?>
```

must be looped, on condition that if you don't have "**hp**" then it will be labeled "**No Phone Number**"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the code you already use

Comment: Thats my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
foreach($datadiri as $data) {
    if(!array_key_exists('hp', $data)) {
        echo 'No Phone Number' . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $data['hp'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Return:

```
No Phone Number
08123456787
```

In your array you have twice the same key.

```
"Bimo Nasuti" => array (
```

You should use some unique ID.

Comment: Thaaaankkkksss broooo :)